# How to create a specific date in Google Script

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-api

I have a spreadsheet that asks people to enter in a day of the month when we need to send out a bill. What I want to do is create a calendar event based on that. So, essentially what I need is an event that starts at the current month, day from the spreadsheet, and continues to a specified point in time.

```
var monthlyDate = row[6]; // Seventh column, monthly date of payment
var curDate = new Date();
var curMonth = curDate.getMonth();
var curYear = curDate.getYear();
curDate.setDate(curMonth, monthlyDate, curYear);
Logger.log("Day of month: %s", monthlyDate);
Logger.log("Current Date: %s", curDate);
Logger.log("Current Date: %s", Date());
```

What I'm seeing is that the monthly date is coming in as a float "6.0" for example, and no matter what I enter in for monthlyDate in the setDate line, it keeps setting the date to 10/9/15 (Today is 10/15/15). I've hard-coded that value to many different numbers, but for some reason it's just not working.

How can I create a date (in any format) that follows the scheme "Current Month / Day from Speadsheet / Current Year" ?

Answer (score 9):

The `getMonth()` method returns a "zero-indexed" number.  So, it returns the number 9 for the 10th month.  `setDate()` doesn't set the date, it sets the "Day of the Month".  The name of that method is misleading.

[Documentation - setDate()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp)

So, the last two parameters that you are using in `setDate()` are doing nothing.  You are setting the day of the month to 9.

If you want to set multiple date parameters at the same time, you need to use the `new Date()` method:

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

The `month` parameter accept values from `0` to `11`, 0 is `Jan` and `11` is `Dec`

[Date Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. How would I use the new Date() function to set the current date, with the sole exception being the actual *day*? As in, what do I need to put in for the year and month? Obviously, I don't want to hardcode 2015, 10.

Comment: If all you want to do is change the day of the current month, you can still use `setDate()`, but you need to enter the right number.  You are getting the date from index 6 of the row.  If that date value is already in the date format, use `var newDayNumber = monthlyDate.getDate();  curDate.setDate(newDayNumber);`